# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow Triggering emails ahead of date

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, date-time, workflow-variable

I want to create a workflow that will look at a date in a column and then send an email 60 or 90 days before that date is current. What would a workflow look like to do that?

Would it be easier to use some other method to set the date to 60 or 90 days ahead in another column? How does Sharepoint prioritize dates? Will I have to make different workflows for each list item or will it be able to scan all dates and say "Here is one that is current, now I'll trigger this email."?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow would look something like this and below **DueDate** is the column in your list. Based on the DueDate - 60 Days you will set the **date** workflow variable and workflow would send email only when **date** variable is met :

Add **-60 days** to **Current Item:Due Date** (Output to **Variable: date**)

then Pause until **Variable: date**

Comment: Did this answer your question Krustoff? If it did then please accept the answer and vote for it. Thanks